# Core data returning an extra array of nill values

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, crash

Getting a real weird error. I have view controller B which fetches an array of objects from CoreData.  When i count and print the results it matches my exceptions of the number of core data objects.

When i use the navigator back button to go to the main view controller I set up some debug code to fetch all core data objects and I am getting one more returned than i would expect, and all the object are nil or 0.

Then when I go back to B sometimes and do a fresh fetch, sometimes I get the expected results and sometimes this extra result is fetched.

The problem is I am using the fetched core data to populate a tableview, so then the number of rows is off by one, and since nil, several optional objets in my cells are not being unwrapped as not expecting nil and therefore getting crashes.

Tried context.reset() at the start of the view controller B.

Not even sure what to show everyone for code.  Doesn't make sense to me.  I did a debug walkthrough of the view controller B and I am not saving any records to core data.

Like I mentioned, sometimes flipping back and forth to main view controller and view controller b sometimes it returns the extra results, sometimes it disappears, and eventually it gets caught and returns nil and crashes.

Thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to fetch in controller B and in the main view controller.

Comment: will do when i am able to.  I found another item, may be because operation is not completing.  When I hit the back button on the navigation controller while the results were fetching it caused all nil entries to be added to core data.  So maybe on the before issue, the results didn't complete fully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those ha in this issue, have a look at your managedobject context through a break point just prior to saving. My issue was after fetching the core data record to modify, I created an insert instance by calling managed object: insertinto. So when I went to save I checked the break point and the context was updating a record and also inserting one. So by deleting the insert I just updated the fetched result.

Comment: I agree with this answer , it is the correct one and as a test you can go to sqlite DB of the app  navigate to 

/Users/<USER>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<DEVICE_ID>/data/Containers/Data/Application/<APPLICATION_ID>/Documents/SingleViewCoreData.sqlite. 

and you will see the actual number of records in DB as expected witch means the extra nulls record came only in select function , it is not inserted .